# Laravel 5.1: Show all selected tags when update article

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, tags, laravel-5.1

I have a problem to show all selected tags when I try to update some article.

I'm newb in laravel and php so, here is my code:

```
<select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($tags as $key => $value)
        @foreach($news->tags as $tag)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" @if($tag->name == $value) selected @endif>{{ $value }}</option>
        @endforeach
   @endforeach
</select>
```

But the result is not that I'm actualy expect:

```
<select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
</select>
```

It must be like this:

```
<select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>3</option>
</select>
```

How can i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this. It's better to put the codes inside the php tag in your controller though, and pass the variables your view.

```
<?php 
$tagsObjectArray = $news->tags->toArray();
$tagsArray = array_column($tagsObjectArray, 'name');
?>
<select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($tags as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" @if(in_array($value, $tagsArray)) selected @endif>{{ $value }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can pass the selected tags to the view and use contains method

```
$tags = Tag::all();
$selectedTags = $article->tags;
return view('YOUR VIEW',[
            'tags' => $tags,
            'selectedTags' => $selectedTags
        ]);
```

in view:

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
     <option value="{{$tag->id}}" @if ($selectedTags->contains($tag->id)) selected @endif>{{$tag->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```